# ASP.NET-Core 2.0 Add/remove routes after application has already started

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a need to add/remove custom routes that were registered during the Configure() method of the Startup class via the IApplicaitonBuilder.  Upon startup I call the MapRoute method within the UseMvc command to register a bunch of custom routes to my controllers which all work as expected.

I would like to create a route management feature that allows the administrator of the API to enable/disable these custom routes which means I need the ability to add/remove routes after the application has already started.

I tried getting access to the IApplicationBuilder via DI in my management controller but could not resolve it.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: why do you need to do it? You could also solve this using some authorization mechanism

Comment: so instead of removing the routes just disallow access in let's say your custom middleware or if you're using MVC just put `[Authorize]` above your controller.

Comment: one place it should be possible to do this is your custom middleware that runs before https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/3a022107dcba43fb6441a5fad741537f17a5fd17/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouterMiddleware.cs

Comment: then all you can do is tinker with `RouteData`

Comment: other than that there's no "Unmap" feature, you could open an issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/ and propose it with the use case.

Comment: What kind of routes are you adding or removing?

Comment: They are essentially route proxies.  My controller can handle routes of any type but users can create their own proxy routes to it which need to be changed during runtime.  I ended up creating my own implementation of IRouter that always has an up to date version of all routes in a custom implementation of RouteCollection.