# Is it possible to change MVC routes after startup?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an .NET Core 2.1 Web API that registers custom routes on startup via the MapRoute method of IRouteBuilder.  This occurs in the Configure() method of startup.

Sometimes these routes need to change and I would like to prevent having to restart the web api in order to add or remove a custom routes.  Is it possible to modify the route table while the web site is running?

Comment: What is `ConfigreRoute`? How will you configure the dynamic routes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET-Core 2.0 Add/remove routes after application has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339412/asp-net-core-2-0-add-remove-routes-after-application-has-already-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom router dynamicly, you could try `IRouter`.

Here is a simple demo to change router at runtime from `appsettings.json` file.

1. appsettings.json

   ```
   {
    "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Warning"
   }
   },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "Router": {
   "Controller": "Home",
   "Action": "Contact"
    }
   }
   ```
2. Custom Router `RouterFromAppSettings`

   ```
   public class RouterFromAppSettings : IRouter
   {
   private readonly IRouter _defaulRouter;
   private readonly IConfiguration _config;
   public RouterFromAppSettings(IRouter defaulRouter
       , IConfiguration config)
   {
       _defaulRouter = defaulRouter;
       _config = config;
   }
   public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   {
       var controller = _config.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Controller");
       var action = _config.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Action");
       context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
       context.RouteData.Values["action"] = action;
       await _defaulRouter.RouteAsync(context);
   }
   public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
   {
       return _defaulRouter.GetVirtualPath(context);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Register custom route

   ```
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.Routes.Insert(0, new RouterFromAppSettings(routes.DefaultHandler,Configuration));

           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });
   ```
4. After launch the appplication, you could change the `appsettings` `Router` node to redirect to different action.

Comment: This is really helpful Tao.  Thank you.  I'm curious how it works because you don't actually set the route handler to anything (it's null).  You populate the route data values which somehow forces the route to the controller and action specified in the route data.  The documentation indicates that it will only be used for routing if the handler is set a non-null handler.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Geekn I passed the defualt router handler by `routes.Routes.Insert(0, new RouterFromAppSettings(routes.DefaultHandler,Configuration));` in `Startup`

Comment: No I get that and I'm going to accept the answer (thank you).  It works perfectly.  All we are doing is adding to route data which seems like what we do when we MapRoute.  I'm just wondering why the default handler always uses whatever controller I add to the route data since the URL doesn't match it if that makes any sense.

Comment: Also do you know if there is already .NET core code that will take a URL path and tell me if it matches a URL template.  I would think the built in router would have to do this by tokenizing the URL and seeing if it matches any route template in the route table.

Comment: @Geekn you may consider checking [Routing](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing) source code to see how it map the url to action.